# os_proc_available_memory get large number

Tags: ios, memory

When i use os_proc_available_memory to get memory, it return large number
2199022788156 * 1024。

Appeared on some devices, iPhone 14, 128gb.
Not all iPhone14

Some one know why? Have you ever encountered it? or any idea？

Answer (score 0):

The `os_proc_available_memory()` function returns bytes. Use the following code to convert it to a more human readable format:

```
 let remainingMemory = ByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: Int64(os_proc_available_memory()), countStyle: .memory)
```